# Is there any parsing when reading 'clean' text file using Scanner?

Tags: java, parsing, io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I know that:

> Parsing is the process of turning some kind of data into another kind
> of data.

But then I also came across this difference between `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`:

> BufferedReader is faster than Scanner because BufferedReader does not
> need to parse the data.

So my question is how is using `Scanner` slower than using `BufferedReader` if I am reading just **text file** (plain characters) and I am not doing any parsing? Is there any parsing I am not aware of?

Or from following code perspective, how is here `Scanner` slower because of **parsing** than using `BufferedReader`?

```
//1
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
    
//2
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

I don't understand quote how `Scanner` is slower because of **parsing**, when I am technically not parsing any data..

Comment: Show your source for those statements?

Comment: But yes, there's parsing to know when the end delimiter is found

Comment: The only way you can determine this is by benchmarking. To be honest, I doubt the different in speed will matter until you get into the hundreds of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing an input stream into lines is a (very limited) form of parsing, but as you say `BufferedReader` can also do that. The difference, if there is one, will be that `BufferedReader` can use a highly-optimised procedure to implement a single use case (divide a stream into lines) while `Scanner` needs to be able to be considerably more flexible (divide a stream into tokens delimited by an arbitrary string or regular expression). Flexibility almost always comes at a price, although you won't know what that cost is without doing some benchmarking. (And it may be very small, since it is conceivable that `Scanner` has optimised algorithms for particular special cases which it can recognise.)

In short, "because parsing" is not a very good explanation for why one interface is slower than another one. But the more flexibly and precisely you parse an input, the more time it is expected to take.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought that term parsing is only used when converting. For example nextInt() would be parse method as it converts String into int. What does parsing mean here? You said dividing stream into lines is form of parsing. But it is technically not converting anything, right?

Comment: @stefan: Parsing means to analyse a string into its constituent parts. Indeed, the similarity between the word "parse" and the word "parts" is not a coincidence; it is actually the etymology of "parse". So in a very primitive sense, you can parse an input into individual lines (or fields). Originally, parsing applied to sentences and meant figuring out which part of speech each word is (and that usage goes back centuries before computers). Conversion really has little to do with parsing; it's at best a side effect.